# asp.net mvc too many queries on one page entity framework parallel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, task-parallel-library

I'm building a web site using asp.net mvc 5.

Currently i'm using dependency injection for injecting per request dbcontext  into my controllers.

But EF is not thread safe so one dbcontext can't be used in parallel queries.

Is it worth to make change to my website so just this page use smt like this?

```
using(var ctx = new dbcontext) {
    //creating a task query like tolistasync
}

using(var ctx2 = new dbcontext) {
    //creating a task query like tolistasync
}

using(var ctx3 = new dbcontext) {
    //creating a task query like tolistasync
}
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
using(var ctx20 = new dbcontext) {
    //creating a task query like tolistasync
}
```

and then:

```
 Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3,......,t20)
```

or should i just use one dbcontext per request and do somthing like this:

```
 var query1result = await query1.ToListAsync();
 var query2result = await query2.ToListAsync();
 var query3result = await query3.ToListAsync();
 var query4result = await query4.ToListAsync();
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 var query19Result = await query19.ToListAsync();
 var query20Result = await query20.ToListAsync();
```

in first case there would be so many opening and closing connection to db.

in second there would be one connection but everything happen sequentially

which case is better an why?

Comment: I don't think any of them will work if you wrap the context in a `using` as that will close the connection before the async task finishes.

Comment: i know that i just did that for the sake of clarifying question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But EF is not thread safe so one dbcontext can't be used in parallel queries.

"Thread safety" is completely different than "supports multiple concurrent operations".

> Is it worth to make change to my website so just this page use smt like this?
>
> which case is better an why?

Only you can answer that question.

However, there is some general guidance.

First, operations against a database are generally I/O-bound, not CPU-bound. Note that there are plenty of exceptions to this rule.

Second, if all/most of the operations are hitting the same database, there's a definite contention going on at the file level.

Third, if the database is on a traditional (i.e., not solid-state) hard drive, there's even more contention going on at the disk platter level.

So, all this is to say that **if** your backend is just a regular SQL Server, then you probably won't see any benefit (i.e., faster response times) from concurrent database operations when the server is under normal load. In fact, in this scenario, you probably won't see any benefit from asynchronous database calls at all (as compared to synchronous calls).

However, **if** your backend is more modern, say, an Azure SQL instance (especially one running on SSDs), then concurrent database operations may indeed speed up your requests.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ask yourself - do you really have performance problems? If no - do it as usual - in one `DbContext`. It's easiest and very safe way.

If you have problems? Let's try:

If your queries is read only, you can run many thread in parallel. Creating new `DbContext` and open new connections - is not a big problem in common. Also, you can call all your read only queries with [`AsNoTracking`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx). So, EF will not cache entities in context.

But, think twice. It's more difficult to debug and find problems in parallel-executing code. So, your operations must be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to deal with a lot of queries, you can run them in parallel. I would use `Parallel.ForEach`.